# Using NSPredicate to determine if a string equals another string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` of CalEvents returned with the `[CalCalendarStore eventPredicateWithStartDate]` method. From the events returned, I am trying to keep only those in which the title of the event == `@"on call"` (case-insensitive).

I am able to keep in the array those events whose title *includes* `@"on call"` with the following code (where 'events' is a 'NSArray' populated with `CalEvents`):

```
NSPredicate *onCallPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.title CONTAINS[c] 'on call')"];
[events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:onCallPredicate];
```

I've tried using a predicate format string like:

`@"SELF.title == 'on call'"` but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Try `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title ==[c] 'on call'"];`

(The `[c]` makes the equality comparison case-insensitive.)

Comment: +1, although you could throw the `[c]` modifier after the `==` to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: Edited it to be case-insensitive.

Comment: Just curious, will MATCH[n] work for == when used without any (*?.) wildcards?

Answer (score 10):

Try predicate with format `@"self.title like[c] 'on call'"`. The following sample code outputs 2 strings:

```
NSArray* ar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"on call", @"I'm on call", @"lala", @"On call", nil];
NSArray* filt = [ar filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self like[c] 'on call'"]];
NSLog([filt description]);

//Output
"on call",
"On call"
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using `==` and `like` for string comparisons?

Comment: Looks like in your case the work they same. But if you want to use wildcards in string comparison then '==' won't work and you'll need to use LIKE instead.