# Want to execute NSString as a formula

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I have a NSString object having multiple conditions specified in it like below:

```
NSString *strFormula1 = @"\"man\" == \"man\" && 1<5 || 12<9";
NSString *strFormula2 = @"\"pac@pac.com\" == \"pac1@pac1.com\" || 9==9 && 8>2 || 2==2";
```

I want to execute formula specified in the NSString object & find out the answer as BOOL. 
Whether the condition specified is returning True or False.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an `NSPredicate` like this:

```
NSString *strFormula1 = @"\"man\" == \"man\" && 1<5 || 12<9";
NSString *strFormula2 = @"\"pac@pac.com\" == \"pac1@pac1.com\" || 9==9 && 8>2 || 2==2";
NSString *strFormula3 = @"\"hello\" == \"world\"";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:strFormula1];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:nil]; //True

predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:strFormula2];
result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:nil]; //True

predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:strFormula3];
result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:nil]; //False
```

And if you're curious to see how the predicate parsed your expression just use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [predicate predicateFormat]);
```

Which in our case returns:

```
("man" == "man" AND 1 < 5) OR 12 < 9 //1st Expression
"pac@pac.com" == "pac1@pac1.com" OR (9 == 9 AND 8 > 2) OR 2 == 2 //2nd Expression
"hello" == "world" //3rd Expression
```

Comment: Parsing the `==`s from the strings to `==`s in Objective-C is probably not a good idea, because this compares memory addresses, not actual string content.

Comment: @Stefan No that is not true for predicates. [See this answer as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967400/using-nspredicate-to-determine-if-a-string-equals-another-string)

Comment: @Stefan Also, what memory addresses? The whole expression is just a string, I'm not passing any objects in there...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I guess you're right... It's a reflex when I see `==`s between strings. :) +1 for your answer then.

Comment: I wish there was an `evaluate` method for this case, rather than `evaluate:nil`, but this works!

Answer (score 1):

Well you need a expression parser and evaluator.

Try this one:
http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm

Comment: This would be a better answer than @rishi's (-1 to him) because Rahul needs something that evaluates the contents of the "`NSString`" objects, but the thing you are pointing to has no C implementation.  Just PHP and Java.  Not necessarily the easiest thing to incorporate into an Objective C app.

Comment: If OP doesn't want to bother with implementing his own parser, what about using the JavaScriptCore framework? It accepts CFStringRefs (so NSStrings are fine) and it has a fully-featured math expression parser, with variables support etc.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a combination of methods, and casting.

Your first forumla would be:

```
if([@"\"man\"" isEqualToString:@"\"man\""] && 1 < 5 || 12 < 9) {
        //Forumla == TRUE
 }
```

If you want to cast it to a BOOL object as `@rishi` stated:

```
BOOL strFormula1 = [@"\"man\"" isEqualToString:@"\"man\""] && 1<5 || 12<9;
```

If you `only` have the string to work with, as `@qianfg` suggested you need to parse the string for integers and strings with some form of regex to determine your variables.

Comment: This still doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: The OP's question is badly worded, in such a way that it's easy to come up with confusing and/or outright incorrect answers.  -1 to the question.