# Unable to parse the format string nspredicate error when using apostrophe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

I am getting this error when entering a keyword in my searchbox:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "(title CONTAINS[c] 'hj'"

I enter any string ('hj' in this case) followed by an apostrophe (or containing an apostrophe
). No apostrophe - no error.

This is what I did:

```
(void)filter:(NSString*)keyword{
    NSString* predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(title CONTAINS[c] '%@')", keyword];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
    self.filteredArray = [self.initialArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

As I said, the code works if  apostrophe character is not included in keyword.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sava, try this:

```
(void)filter:(NSString*)keyword{
    NSString *keywordWithBackslashedApostrophes = [keyword stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
    NSString* predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[c] '%@'", keywordWithBackslashedApostrophes];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
    self.filteredArray = [self.initialArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

The main difference from your code is that an apostrophe in the keyword is replaced by backslash-apostrophe.

Answer (score 3):

I too had problems with this predicate filter I had customer names like O'Connor and the query used to fail. The solution suggested by Alexey Golikov works fine, but I would like to know if there is any NSPredicate class level fix for this. String operations are always a costly thing you may not want to do it until necessary.

-anoop

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967400/using-nspredicate-to-determine-if-a-string-equals-another-string) 
You can do everything as in `predicateWithFormat` without the quotes

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[c] '%@'", keyword]
```

Comment: yep, but try to do that with the single predicateWithFormat, no need to expand it with a stringWithFormat I guess

Answer (score 0):

The problem is creating an NSString when you don't need to do that. Notice here that we don't need an NSString variable, and we removed the apostrophes from `%@`.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(title CONTAINS[c] %@)", keyword];
```